# get element from json array in angular 2

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular

I am trying to do something elementary. I have json file pageDefinition.json which is loaded into my component. This is how json looks like:

```
...
"testArray": [
    {"id": 0, "name": "row1"},
    {"id": 1, "name": "row2"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "row3"}
  ],
...
```

When I print all array with `{{pageDefinition?.testArray | json}}` it works. But I want to get only one item with index from array. If I try to get first element: `{{pageDefinition?.testArray[0] | json}}` app crash with exception:

```
EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null in [

  {{pageDefinition?.testArray[0] | json}}

   in ExampleFile@10:8]
```

Where did I make a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use this longer version

```
{{pageDefinition?.testArray ? pageDefinition.testArray[0] : null | json}}
```

The safe navigation variant (i.e., Elvis operator) is only available for `.` not for `[]` accessor operators.

Comment: Thanks @MarkRajcok I'm prone to mix f and v in words like "life" and "safe". Thanks for fixing!